# Laravel's Input:all() ignores disabled inputs

Tags: php, html, laravel

While var_dumping the content of `Input:all()` with Laravel 4, I noticed that an input generated with the following code is ignored by the framework:

```
{{ Form::text('departure', 'Departure', array('class' => 'form-control', 'disabled')) }}
```

But that the following works as expected:

```
{{ Form::text('departure', 'Departure', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

I have a good reason to disable the user messing with what is in this input field. Yet I need to save it in the database. How should I do this? Disable the `disabled` attribute with jQuery when the user submits the form? That's a bit ridiculous, isn't it?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Just change `disabled` to `readonly`

Comment: It worked, thanks! Didn't know this HTML attribute. I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm allowed to.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bad idea to rely on HTML flags like `disabled` or `readonly`. The user can easily open up the inspector and change the value of the field. Don't expose this at all in the template, this is business logic which belongs in the model!

Are you looping over Input::all() to save the fields to the database? If so, you could write  something like this:

```
$allowedFields = ["field1", "field2", "field3" ...];
foreach($allowedFields as $field) {
    if(Input::has($field) {
        $myEloquentModel->{$field} = Input::get($field);
    }
}
$myEloquentModel->save();
```

Benefits: checks only allowed fields, updates only present fields in the actual request.

Comment: `Input::only("field1", "field2")` is a helper function for exactly this.

Comment: Actually those variables that I store are Javascript values which I get from the W3C Geolocation API. I know there's the risk that the user will change them but I can't do without Javascript in this case, can I?